# JqGrid Blank value in dropdown List

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I want to show a blank value in dropdown list , i am using the code like this , but this make a dropdownlist in which blank value comes at last , and by default selected , i want blank value at first and by default selected

```js
{name: 'AuditLevel', index: 'levels', align: 'center', width: 15,
editable: true, edittype: 'select',
editoptions: { value: {' ': ' ',1: 'Level1', 2: 'Level2', 3: 'Level3' }}
```

Any Solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exists because you use *object form* of `editoptions.value`. The only way to read such `editoptions.value` object in JavaScript is *enumeration* of properties of the object (with loop like `var prop; for (prop in editoptions.value)`). The problem is that the order of the properties in the case could be not the same as the order in which you wrote the properties during initialization of the object.

So you should use *string form* if the order of the properties are important for you:

```js
editoptions: { value: " : ;1:Level1;2:Level2:3:Level3" }
```

would be better as

```js
editoptions: { value: {' ': ' ',1: 'Level1', 2: 'Level2', 3: 'Level3' }
```

jqGrid will split the string `" : ;1:Level1;2:Level2:3:Level3"` by `;` and then it will use `:` as the separator between the value and the text of options. If the text (or the value) of the options contains the separators `:` or `;` you can use another separators, but you have to inform using `separator` (it's default value is ":") and `delimiter` property (it's default value is ";"). For example

```js
editoptions: {
    value: " ↣ |1↣Level1|2↣Level;2|3↣Level:3"
    delimiter: "|",
    separator: "↣"
}
```

Comment: now i want to disable this column on the click of radiobutton , can u help me ? 
{name: 'Result', index: 'Result', width: 30, editable: true, formatter: 'dynamicText',edittype: 'custom', editoptions: { custom_element: radioelem, custom_value: radiovalue }
},

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580022/disable-the-dropdown-on-clicking-on-radiobutton

i know , there is so much code and detail in the question , but really i stuck at this point ,